# convert text "JobTask" to "job_task" with ruby

Tags: ruby

I have these strings:

```
"job_task"
"employ_task"
"post_task"
```

with:

```
22] pry(main)> j = "job_task".classify
=> "JobTask"
```

I wat to get the the opposite result:

from:

```
"JobTask"
"EmployTask"
"PostTask"
```

i want to get:

```
"job_task"
"employ_task"
"post_task"
```

thank you!

Comment: Since `classify` is a `rails` method can we assume you are using rails? If so the method you are looking for is called `underscore` and can be found here [`ActiveSupport::Inflector::underscore`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/underscore). This method is patched into `String` as simply `def underscore;  ActiveSupport::Inflector.underscore(self); end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convert(str)
  str.gsub(/\p{Ll}?\p{Lu}/) {|s| (s.size == 1 ? "" : "#{s[0]}_") + "#{s[-1].downcase}"}
end

convert("JobTask")    #=> "job_task"
convert("EmployTask") #=> "employ_task"
convert("PostTask")   #=> "post_task"
```

`/\p{Ll}/` and `/\p{Lu}/` respectively match a lowercase and uppercase letter. See [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html(search for `"\p{Lu}"`).

The regular expression can be read, "optionally match a lowercase letter followed by a (required) uppercase letter." If only a single character is matched (the first letter of the string), `s[-1]` is the same as `s`.

For

```
str = "JobTask"
```

The block converts `"J"` to `"j"` and `"T"` to `"_t"`:

A lazy alternative is the following.

```
def convert(str)
  str.gsub(/\p{Lu}/) { |s| "_#{s.downcase}" }[1..-1]
end
```

Here

```
"JobTask".gsub(/\p{Lu}/) { |s| "_#{s.downcase}" }
  # => "_job_task"
```

`[1..-1]` return this string without the leading underscore.

Comment: `convert("ABCTask") => "abctask"`. I would expect `abc_task` or even `abct_ask`. Here's the ActiveSupport source code for `.underscore`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L92-L101

Comment: @Kimmo, good point. And with the lazy variant,  `convert("ABCTask") #=> "a_b_c_task"`. However, more information is needed as to what is desired if data were to deviate in form from that in the examples.

Comment: @kimmolehto `ActiveSupport` would convert that to `a_b_c_task` unless `ABC` was defined as an inflection acronym.